# Why doesn't this code work (Leetcode in Python)?

Tags: python

```
class Solution:
    def isHappy(self, n):
        list_n, l, ls, num = [n,], 0, 0, 0
        while num != 1:
            if l != ls:
                return False
            num = sum([int(i)**2 for i in list(str(n))])
            list_n.append(num)
            l, ls = len(list_n), len(set(list_n))
        return True
```

**Input: 7**

**Output: `False`**

**Expected: `True`**

It's from Happy Number | LeetCode OJ

Write an algorithm to determine if a number is "happy".

A happy number is a number defined by the following process: Starting with any positive integer, replace the number by the sum of the squares of its digits, and repeat the process until the number equals 1 (where it will stay), or it loops endlessly in a cycle which does not include 1. Those numbers for which this process ends in 1 are happy numbers.

Comment: why is it a class? Also `sum(int(i)**2 for i in list(str(n)))` would be better, you are building a list for no reason

Comment: The moment `list_n` has repeated values, it will return `False`

Comment: It's built as a class because I copied it from OJ.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion on my list comprehension.

Comment: I know that my list maybe duplicated to see such a sequence. However, for happy number, would the list be duplicated before it contains several one? Once num equals one, it supposes to quit the while loop. bi

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `sum(int(i)**2 for i in str(n))` would be even better, you're still building a list for no reason :-P

Comment: @StefanPochmann, In my defence  I was distracted still trying to understand why the code was in a class!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question: Your code fails because you're confusing `num` and `n`. In particular, you compute `num` always from `n`, and neither ever changes. Just get rid of one of them, that will also be less confusing. You really should learn to debug, btw... printing `num` or `n` inside the loop would have made it clear what's happening.

Using a set would btw be easier and faster, try that as well. Here's one way:

```
def isHappy(n):
    stop = {1}
    while n not in stop:
        stop.add(n)
        n = sum(int(d)**2 for d in str(n))
    return n == 1
```

And here's one that only uses two single ints. Can you see how it works?

```
def isHappy(n):
    s = lambda n: sum(int(d)**2 for d in str(n))
    m = s(n)
    while m != n:
        n, m = s(n), s(s(m))
    return n == 1
```

Comment: I don't see where this answers the question. The question asks what's wrong with the given code. The question does not ask for a solution to the happy-number problem.

Comment: @RobKennedy I answered that now. Is it ok now?

Comment: Thank you~your solution is as well very enlightening.

Comment: God I love the lambda solution! I am a newbie in programming and really appreciate such help!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is as below:

n has to be reset to newest result after each sum operation. So just add this line before `return True` :

`n=num`

And for your reference, here is the working code:

```
def isHappy(n):
list_n, l, ls, num = [n,], 0, 0, 0
while num != 1:
    if l != ls:
        return False
    num = sum([int(i)**2 for i in list(str(n))])
    list_n.append(num)
    l, ls = len(list_n), len(set(list_n))
    n=num # reset n after each sum calculation
return True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep looping while `sm` which is the sum of the squares of the digits of the current n or until `sm` is repeated. Returning `sm == 1` to test if the number is happy:

```
def isHappy( n):
    # set initial sum of squares
    sm = sum(int(i) * int(i) for i in str(n))
    seen = set()
    # while we have not hit 1 or we get a repeated `sm`
    while sm != 1 and sm not in seen:
        # add sm to our set
        seen.add(sm)
        # update sm
        sm = sum(int(i) * int(i) for i in str(sm))
    # we will get here either when sm is 1 or we had a repeated sm
    return sm == 1
```

Output:

```
In [2]: for x in range(100+1):
   ...:     if isHappy(x):
   ...:           print(x)
   ...:         
1
7
10
13
19
23
28
31
32
44
49
68
70
79
82
86
91
94
97
100
```

As per the wiki page description in your question *If n is not happy, then its sequence does not go to 1. Instead, it ends in the cycle* so if we see repeated values we know the number is not happy.  I don't see anywhere in your code that you are checking that condition.