# how to understand happy number from leetcode

Tags: python

Here is the problem from leetcode:

Write an algorithm to determine if a number is "happy".
A happy number is a number defined by the following process: Starting with any positive integer, replace the number by the sum of the squares of its digits, and repeat the process until the number equals 1 (where it will stay), or it loops endlessly in a cycle which does not include 1. Those numbers for which this process ends in 1 are happy numbers.

```
Example: 19 is a happy number    

1^2 + 9^2 = 82
8^2 + 2^2 = 68
6^2 + 8^2 = 100
1^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 = 1
```

Question 1: From my understanding, if 1 happens, `return True` else it will infinitely run the loop, where I understand from this sentence "or it loops endlessly in a cycle which does not include 1."

However, after I found some answer to this questions from the internet, I found my understanding was wrong. It is supposed to be if 1 happens `return True`, **also if any number repeats in the set, then end the loop and return False.** Well, to be honest, the problem says "or it loops endlessly in a cycle which does not include 1." Why we just let the program run endlessly in a cycle as it states??

Questions 2: For the second question, I think it is about understanding the code. This is what I found from [internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30247583/why-doesnt-this-code-work-leetcode-in-python):

```
def isHappy(n):
    stop = {1}
    while n not in stop:
        stop.add(n)
        n = sum(int(d)**2 for d in str(n))
    return n == 1
```

From this codes, I can understand that if 1 happens, it will stop running the while loop and `return True`. However, if a number is repeated in the set, I think it also will stop running the `while` loop and `return True`, because next line followed by `while` statement will still `return n==1`. However, in fact it will output `False`.

[image: set of happy numbers]

Since 89 repeats again in the set, the output is False.
Sorry, for my wordy description. Simply speaking, my questions is: How does this `False` come out? In the coding, there is no place explicitly `return False`.

Comment: What does `n == 1` evaluate to?

Comment: I see!!@Hurkyl n if = to 1 then return true otherwise return false!Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The *isHappy* function you posted is correct.

This is how it works -

1. It will calculate the squares of the digits and save it in n.
2. If n is 1 it stops. Else, it appends n to change list and loops. But as soon as n is any number which is there in the change list, the loop breaks.
3. In Python, when control comes out of the loop, it has the last values stored in variables. So, n has the last calculation stored.
4. Now, if n is 1, n == 1 returns True else False.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Why would you *need* to replace a `set` with a `list`?

Comment: How is a List better than a Set for storing non repeating numbers?

Comment: Oops sorry, I am sleepy and saw it as dictionary. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did , even though it is a bit messy

```
    #Python program to check if a number is a happy number

    #Creating an user defined function which returns True if the number is happy else False
    def happy(num) :

        #Creating a copy of the number in a string and a iterating point
        copy = str(num)
        square = num

        #Proceeding with while loop due to unknown iterations
        while True : #inifinte loop
    
            square = sum(int(j) ** 2 for j in list(str(square))) #Sum of the number's digit squares
    
            if square == 1:
                test = True
                break
    
            elif square == 4:
                test = False
                break
    
        return test

    check = int(input('Enter the number: '))
    print('The number {} {} a happy number'.format(check, ('is') if happy(check) == True else ('is not')))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. if the n is 1 or 7 return true.
2. till n > 9, sum the square of digits of the number n.
3. if the sum of square of digits is < 9 and sum == 1 or sum == 7 return true.
4. else return false.

Answer (score -1):

below is a popular solution to the happy number problem. this key is the sum of square of each digit did not appear in the past, otherwise, there will be an endless loop.

```
class Solution:
    # @param {integer} n
    # @return {boolean}
    def isHappy(self, n):
        s=set()
        while n!=1 and n not in s:
            s.add(n)
            n= sum([int(x)**2 for x in str(n)])
        return n==1
```